# Getting devices information

Tags: windows, id

Is there any freeware app to list the pci and usb devices under windows. I'm looking for something like lspci/lsusb. I'm interested in the vendor and device ids mostly. It needs to list devices that are not registered with the systems device manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[SIW](http://www.gtopala.com/)** is an advanced System Information for Windows tool that gathers detailed information about your system properties and settings and displays it in an extremely comprehensible manner.

In the **Hardware** section of the navigation pane, click **PCI** and you will get this:

[image]

Now highlight a device in the top part of the main window to retrieve most detailed information.

*SIW is free and [portable](http://www.gtopala.com/download/siw.exe).*

Answer (score 1):

[SiSoftware Sandra](http://www.sisoftware.net/index.html?dir=&location=pinformation&langx=en&a=) (the System ANalyser, Diagnostic and Reporting Assistant)

> SiSoftware Sandra is an information & diagnostic
>   utility. It should provide most of the
>   information (including undocumented)
>   you need to know about your hardware,
>   software and other devices whether
>   hardware or software.
>
> It works along the lines of other
>   Windows utilities, however it tries to
>   go beyond them and show you more of
>   what's really going on. Giving the
>   user the ability to draw comparisons
>   at both a high and low-level. You can
>   get information about the CPU,
>   chipset, video adapter, ports,
>   printers, sound card, memory, network,
>   Windows internals, AGP, PCI, PCI-X,
>   PCIe (PCI Express), database, USB,
>   USB2, 1394/Firewire, etc.

The version named Sandra Lite is non-commercial freeware. Since a download link for it is somewhat hard to find on sisoftware.net, here it is on [filehippo](http://www.filehippo.com/download_sandra_lite/).

[image]

Comment: Not exactly freeware though ;)

Comment: well, Sandra Lite is free.

Comment: As sisoftware.net tries hard to hide Sandra Lite, I added a link.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?
Hack #116: [Uncover Hidden Hardware with the Device Manager](http://oreilly.com/pub/h/3105).

If that does not work for you, there is a free software called [Belarc Advisor](http://www.belarc.com/free_download.html).